# Chart.js tooltip not showing

Tags: javascript, charts

I am attempting to add tooltips to my chart, the options are correctly loading, however tooltips are not showing, any ideas?

```
        <script>

        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(139, 157, 195, 1)",
                    strokeColor : "#4c66a4",
                    pointColor : "#fff",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#3b5998",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    data : [{{implode(',', $fanCounts)}}]

                }
            ]
        }

        var options = {
                    showTooltips: true,
                    tooltipEvents: ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"],
                    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
                }

        var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("fancanvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData, options);

        </script>
```

I have also changed the chart.js global config to enable tooltips for line charts.

Comment: This solution by Chatri Sae-Tung worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24722857/2595830

Comment: My problem was caused by the shared `config` variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47519851/722036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        showTooltips: true,
        multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
    });
```

use this (global settings)

Answer (score 27):

For anyone having problems with this using Chartjs v3, you need to make sure you have registered the Tooltip plugin:

```
import { Chart, Tooltip } from 'chart.js'

Chart.register([Tooltip])
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Such a simple thing to overlook.

Comment: Hi All,

import....

leads in my case to "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".

I simply added the import statement to my main js file...

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Andreas. Without knowing more about the rest of you project its difficult to help you, but I would advice you to check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655153/11722925.

Comment: @ZdeněkBednařík it depends on your project. As long as it is executed is the only requirements. Here is an example with React: https://github.com/Jesperpaulsen/data-collector/blob/main/packages/data-visualizer/src/components/common/Charts/ChartRenderer.tsx#L16

Answer (score -1):

You just need to put background with a single value:

```
datasets: [{
    label: "# of beauty womens",
    data: [12, 5, 3],
    backgroundColor: "#FC940B",
    fill: false,
    borderColor: "#FC940B"
}]
```

Hugs...