# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using ArcGIS JSAPI 4.12 and wish to use [Spatial Illusions](https://github.com/spatialillusions/milsymbol) to draw military symbols on a map.

When I add `milsymbol.js` to the script, the console returns error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

so I add `type="module"` to the script, and then it returns

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ms is not defined

Here's my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/"></script>
<script type="module" src="milsymbol-2.0.0/src/milsymbol.js"></script>

<script>
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
    ], function (Map, MapView, MapImageLayer, FeatureLayer) {

        var symbol = new ms.Symbol("SFG-UCI----D", { size: 30 }).asCanvas(3);
        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "topo-vector"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            center: [121, 23],
            zoom: 7
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, whether I add `type="module"` or not, there are always errors. However, in the official document of Spatial Illusions, there isn't any `type="module"` in the script. I'm now really confused. How do they manage to get it work without adding the type?

#### File *milsymbol.js*

```
import { ms } from "./ms.js";

import Symbol from "./ms/symbol.js";
ms.Symbol = Symbol;

export { ms };
```

Comment: This question is in the top 10 of all [21,642,537 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) on Stack Overflow in terms of [***view rate***](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) (presumably from search engine hits). It has got about 1800 views per day over its lifetime.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Probably because the title made it look like much more generic than it actually is.

Answer (score 759):

### Update For Node.js / NPM

Add [`"type": "module"`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) to your [`package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_type) file.

```json
{
  // ...
  "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

**Note**: When using modules, if you get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`,  you'll need to use the [`import` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) instead of [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireid). You can't natively mix and match between them, so you'll need to pick one or [use a bundler if you need to use both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068668/1366033).

Comment: Yes. Basically, don't run TypeScript scripts independently, but put them in an existing Angular project and things will work fine ;-)

Comment: @wormsparty [Escape the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719868/8211365)

Answer (score 618):

I got this error because I forgot the `type="module"` inside the script tag:

```html
<script type="module" src="whatever.js"></script>
```

Comment: THANKS. do you know why this doesn't work if i add `"type": "module"` to my package.json?

Comment: @backwardforward this is because package.json is for nodejs, which runs on the server. your problem is happening when the script is loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 226):

It looks like the cause of the errors are:

1. You're currently loading the source file in the `src` directory instead of the built file in the `dist` directory (you can see what the intended distributed file is [here](https://github.com/spatialillusions/milsymbol/blob/master/package.json#L5)). This means that you're using the native source code in an unaltered/unbundled state, leading to the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. This should be fixed by using the bundled version since the package is [using rollup](https://github.com/spatialillusions/milsymbol/blob/master/package.json#L15) to create a bundle.
2. The reason you're getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError: ms is not defined` error is because modules are scoped, and since you're loading the library using native modules, `ms` is not in the global scope and is therefore not accessible in the following script tag.

It looks like you should be able to load the `dist` version of this file to have `ms` defined on the `window`. Check out [this example](https://spatialillusions.com/milsymbol/example.html#speed-canvas) from the library author to see an example of how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I know I have the wrong file. I've been looking for the dist version of the file but with no result. Do you know any way to get the dist version? Thanks so much!

Comment: It's available for download on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/milsymbol). Alternatively, you could build it yourself by cloning the repo and running one of the build scripts. It looks like there's an AMD build script (https://github.com/spatialillusions/milsymbol/blob/master/package.json#L14) that should allow you to `require` the built package directly into your code.

Comment: I've downloaded through npm, now I have script : `<script src="node_modules/milsymbol/dist/milsymbol.js"></script>`, but the console still returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: ms is not defined`. The issue is `ms` is not defined in the `dist/milsymbol.js`, it's defined in `src/milsymbol.js`, but it requires `type="module"` and will cause scope problem. Is there any solution for this. Thanks so much!

Comment: What if thats the actual intention, referencing it from /src. As the author is not planning to expose a property of a class for example..

Answer (score 113):

I resolved my case by replacing `import` with `require`:

```
// import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
const parse = require('node-html-parser');
```

Comment: ```const {parse} = require('node-html-parser');``` worked for me

Comment: What is the explanation? Why does this work? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61809626/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: the question was about browser

Comment: This answer is useful in NodeJs if you want to keep it old school. But it's not related to the question

Comment: How are answers like that real? a) This is 100 % NOT A SOLUTION TO A PROBLEM b) Where is the explanation of what is happening?

Comment: I believe the reason involves es vs commonjs modules

Answer (score 94):

## There are several common ways to resolve the conflict associated with the above issue

**1. The first: In the script, include `type=module`**

```html
<script type="module" src="milsymbol-2.0.0/src/milsymbol.js"></script>
```

> **This is the most recommended way to fix the issue** 
> By adding the `type="module"` attribute, you are telling the browser that the script should be treated as an ECMAScript module, and it should use the appropriate rules for resolving dependencies and executing the code.

---

**2. The second: In node.js, into your `package.json` file**

```json
{
  "type": "module",
}
```

> Restart the project `npm start`

---

**3. The third: replace import by require()**

> `Try this`

```js
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
parse = require('node-html-parser');
```

> `Else try this`

```js
// import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
parse = require('node-html-parser');
```

Comment: What if all 3 of those don't work. I want a simple api.js file with tons of reusable global functions that I don't want to have to import one at a time ever. ie: <script id="apijs" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/api.js"></script>

Comment: Are these 3 ways AND or OR. And how to use these in NextJS .

Comment: Adding `"type": "module"` in `package.json` works with node v18.

Comment: @LonelySoul these are the 3  ways which are the most common fix for the conflict with the above issue

Answer (score 62):

I was also facing the same issue until I added the type="module" to the script.

Before it was like this

```
<script src="../src/main.js"></script>
```

And after changing it to

```
<script type="module" src="../src/main.js"></script>
```

It worked perfectly.

Comment: Getting CORS on doing this

Comment: Meaning you're requesting from another domain. You can fix that by adding ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *``` in your headers. You can check the MDN docs about CORS  at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests.

Comment: no i know about cors , the thing is these are my local files

Comment: You need to serve your script in an http server, browsers use an http request to load es6 modules, the server needs to respond in the header a CORS allowing your origin.

Comment: the simplest way: you can use http-server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122981/935330

Comment: This answer was already given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679392/5468463

Answer (score 61):

> Applicable for node 12. This answer is no longer maintained for new node versions. Feel free to comment solutions for more recent versions.

I solved this issue by doing the following:

When using ECMAScript 6 modules from the browser, use the .js extension in your files, and in the script tag add `type = "module"`.

When using ECMAScript 6 modules from a Node.js environment, use the extension `.mjs` in your files and use this command to run the file:

```
node --experimental-modules filename.mjs
```

Edit: This was written when node12 was the latest LTS, this does not apply to node 14 LTS.

Comment: _Modules: ECMAScript modules: Enabling_ `https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling`

Comment: This is no longer necessary. Simply add "type": "module" to your package.json and everything will work as expected. (Use .js for filename extensions)

Comment: We can use `.cjs` files as well.

Comment: Must add that I was only getting this error when running my jest tests. I had to add file jest.config.mjs (specifically mjs extension) to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 33):

I don't know whether this has appeared obvious here. I would like to point out that as far as client-side (browser) JavaScript is concerned, you can add `type="module"` to both external as well as internal js scripts.

Say, you have a file 'module.js':

```
var a = 10;
export {a};
```

You can use it in an external script, in which you do the import, eg.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script type="module" src="test.js"></script><!-- Here use type="module" rather than type="text/javascript" -->
</body></html>
```

test.js:

```
import {a} from "./module.js";
alert(a);
```

You can also use it in an internal script, eg.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script type="module">
    import {a} from "./module.js";
    alert(a);
</script>
</body></html>
```

It is worthwhile mentioning that for relative paths, you must not omit the "./" characters, ie.:

```
import {a} from "module.js";     // this won't work
```

Comment: For those arriving here with a Rails 7 problem. I found add the `type="module"` like so <%= javascript_include_tag 'someScript', type: "module"  %>` where `app/javascript/someScript.js`. I didn't understand that this is something like a script tag. This moved the issue along to `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ol/Map". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Answer (score 25):

If you want to use import instead of require() for modules, change or add the value of `type` to `module` in `package.json` file

Example:

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "appsample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "Learning Node",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Chikeluba Anusionwu",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```
import http from 'http';

var host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = 1992,
    server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.end("I am using type module in package.json file in this application.");
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(
    'Listening to server ${port}. Connection has been established.'));
```

Answer (score 22):

For me, it was caused by not referencing a library (specifically `typeORM`, using the `ormconfig.js` file, under the `entities` key) to the `src` folder, instead of the `dist` folder...

```
   "entities": [
      "src/db/entity/**/*.ts", // Pay attention to "src" and "ts" (this is wrong)
   ],
```

instead of

```
   "entities": [
      "dist/db/entity/**/*.js", // Pay attention to "dist" and "js" (this is the correct way)
   ],
```

Answer (score 16):

I got this error in [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) and fixed it with the following steps:

1. Go to the *project root directory*, and open the *Package.json* file for editing.
2. Add `"type":"module";`
3. Save it and restart the server.

Answer (score 15):

Add "type": "module", to your *package.json* file.

And restart your application:

`npm start`

Then your problem is solved.

Comment: Is the comma part of it or not?

Comment: @PeterMortensen you are adding an item to a JSON object, items are delimited with commas, so unless you add it at the end you need a comma.

Comment: But I'm not writing a module?

Comment: Missing script: "start"

Comment: The question does not mention node.js at all.

Answer (score 11):

Why this occurs and more possible causes:

A lot of interfaces still do not understand [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) JavaScript syntax/features. Hence there is need for ES6 to be compiled to [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition) whenever it is used in any file or project.

The possible reasons for the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error is you are trying to run the file independently. You are yet to install and set up an ES6 compiler such as [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) or the path of the file in your runscript is wrong/not the compiled file.

If you will want to continue without a compiler, the best possible solution is to use ES5 syntax, which in your case would be `var ms = require(./ms.js);`. This can later be updated as appropriate or better still set up your compiler and ensure your file/project is compiled before running and also ensure your run script is running the compiled file usually named dist, build or whatever you named it and the path to the compiled file in your runscript is correct.

Comment: Thank you. This is one of only two answers that tries to get at the root cause.
I would expect Node.js 15.5 to support this 2016 feature though, and yet I'm finding it doesn't?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because as @goldfishalpha says, it is the only answer that goes to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I'm coding on vanilla JavaScript. If you're doing same, simply add a type="module" to your script tag.

That is, previous code:

```html
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Updated code:

```html
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>`
```

Comment: Please do not repeat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679392/5468463

Comment: @Vega it's not duplicate of mentioned answer. As you can notice, this answer suggested to add type="module" for developer's script definition, your linked answer suggests to mark library's script definition. I've encountered the same error and solved it only using this answer.

Comment: The above answer suggests to add type="module", it says: _...because I forgot the type="module" inside the script tag_, so does your answer. What is the exact difference?

Comment: In addition, there is https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015812/5468463,https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015812/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085377/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899085/5468463, etc

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015812/3734116

Answer (score 9):

For me this helped:

1. In the .ts file I used: `import prompts from "prompts";`
2. And used `"module": "commonjs"` in file *tsconfig.json*

Comment: What *.ts* file is it?

Comment: It is any typeScript or JavaScript file your code needs some module import added.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same error by EXPO.

Mainly the solution is that to add `"type": "module",` in the package.json file.

[image: my files, you can find two package.json]

[image: Code Image]

However, you have to check that which is your correct package.json.

In my case, there are two package.json files, then you should add that to the server file.

To identify which is correct package.json, find `"scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" },`

Below ↑　this line, add `"type": "module",`

Comment: What is "EXPO"?

Comment: https://expo.dev/

Comment: may i ask what that theme is : )

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, if my memory is correct, this theme is cyberpunk 2077 (beta). But I am not sure, I changed it sooner from the last comment.

Comment: LOL, I like the pictures

Answer (score 4):

None of the provided answers worked for me, but I found a different solution from: *[How to enable ECMAScript 6 imports in Node.js](https://timonweb.com/javascript/how-to-enable-ecmascript-6-imports-in-nodejs/)*

Install ESM:

```
npm install --save esm
```

Run with ESM:

```
node -r esm server.js
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is triggered because the file you're linking to in your HTML file is the unbundled version of the file.
To get the full bundled version you'll have to install it with `npm`:

```
npm install --save milsymbol
```

This downloads the full package to your `node_modules` folder.

You can then access the standalone minified JavaScript file at `node_modules/milsymbol/dist/milsymbol.js`

You can do this in any directory, and then just copy the below file to your `/src` directory.

Comment: `--save`'s been default since `npm 5` & `node 8` (2017): https://stackoverflow.com/q/36022926/1821548, https://nodejs.dev/npm-dependencies-and-devdependencies, https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/884, https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-node8-and-npm5/

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error while trying to use import [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js).

Instead of   `import express from 'express';`

I used   `const express = require('express');`

Answer (score 3):

Use this code. It worked well for me:

Add this script tag to file *index.html*:

```
<script type="module">
    import { ms } from "./ms.js";
    import Symbol from "./ms/symbol.js";
</script>
```

Comment: it was already given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679392/5468463

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I updated

```
"lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
```

with

```
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
]
```

in my *tsconfig.json* file.

Comment: Thank you, your comment lead me to install:  @babel/preset-env, and with that npm install, I am able to use the import statement.

Answer (score 2):

I had to import some data from an external file (JavaScript file), to my *script.js* file present in my HTML file.

#### File *data.js*

```
const data = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

By adding `type=module` I got [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) error.

I found out that I can import file *data.js* into my *script.js* file just by including file *data.js* inside my HTML file.

For example, previously my HTML file consists of

```html
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>
```

As I required some data from file *data.js*, I just changed my HTML file to:

```html
<script src="assets/data.js"></script>
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>
```

I.e., include file *data.js* before file *script.js*, giving access to my data variable inside file *script.js*.

Comment: Could you show how you use `data.js` inside `script.js`? The `script.js` contains no import statements?

Comment: @parsecer, Yes there are no import statements inside `script.js` file. For example. `data.js` can have `const data_js_variable = 1` and we can use this variable inside `script.js` without the need of any import statements. We just have to include the js files in order inside our html file like```<script src="assets/data.js"></script>
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case, I didn't want to update my *package.json* file and change the file type to mjs.

So I was looking around and found out that changing the module in file *tsconfig.json* affected the result. My *ts.config* file was:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Like this and changing the module from `"module": "es2020"` to `"module" : "commonjs"` solved my issue.

I was using [MikroORM](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm) and thought maybe it doesn't support any module above [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS).

Answer (score 1):

try add **.babelrc**

```
{
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "node": "12"
      },
      "modules": "commonjs"
    }
  ]
] }
```

Comment: Add the file or add something to the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NextJS, maybe your code should be use on the client (brower) side only.
Try replace the component in the Page by a dynamic import with "ssr: false" like this in '/pages/my-page':

```
[...]
const MyClientSideOnlyComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/Component'), {ssr: false});
    
return   <MyClientSideOnlyComponent/>
[...]
```

instead of

```
return <Component/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add this note because it was not apparently obvious to me. You need to add `type="module"` to all script includes, not just the one you want to use for your utility file.

index.html:

```
<script type="module" src="js/controllers/utils.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>`
```

main.js:

```
import myFunction from './utils.js
```

utils.js:

```
export default myFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to import functions from module.
let's say, `main.js` has `func1` and `func2` defined, and you want to import those to function to a new module say, `test.js`

Below will solve the problem.

main.js:

```
const func1 = () => {console.log('do sth in func1')};
const func2 = () => {console.log('do sth in func2')};

//at the end of module
//export specific functions here
module.exports = { func1, func2 };
```

test.js :

```
// import them here
const{ func1, func2} = require('./main.js');
func1();
func2();
```

Comment: survey.js -> main.js

Answer (score 0):

Following worked, inline export gave issue but export at the end of fn following worked.
const xxx = async(....)

module.exports = {
xxx,
};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue in the [Cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) TypeScript framework then the below fix is working.

In the *cucumber.json* file, mention as below. Install the ts-node.

```
{
    "default":{
        "requireModule":[
            "ts-node/register"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to create a separate module file, and then changing the type to module, which might cause other errors.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you haven't exported. The .ts file requires an export class format, whereas in a .js file we would use the `exports` function.

So, we have to use `var_name = require("<pathfile>")` to use those file functions.

Comment: Hello...
Inspect // Watch ...
Your answer is poorly elaborated.
It is useful to insert an effective response, with codes and references. Concluding a practical and efficient solution.
This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community and learn how to post;

Answer (score -1):

Use

```html
<script type="module" src="/src/moduleA.js"></script>
```

instead of

```html
<script>System.import("/src/moduleA.js")</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've added this in the [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file and it fixed it.
I was having this issue when trying to run the mockttp!

```javascript
"ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "the mockttp"?

Answer (score -6):

Just add `.pack` between the name and the extension in the `<script>` tag in `src`.

I.e.:

```
<script src="name.pack.js">
    // Code here
</script>
```

Answer (score -8):

This error occurs when it fails in [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) transpile.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30304177)

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with bable transpile