# Struggling to start hello world in react

Tags: reactjs

It seems that many people struggle to make the initial hello world for React and I can seem to find a solution to my problem. Here is my test.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<h1>hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world should appear below: </p>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <!--React script-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to follow the example given on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44) and this the error that I am getting. I've tried adding type="modal", but it did not help.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOk3Y.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure there is an error. You are running javascript ES6 in your browser when you do this line `<script src="test.js"></script>`

Browsers only read javascript ES5.

You miss the webpack compilation step, using `babel-loader`. It's gonna make a bundle in javascript ES5 ready to be opened by browsers.