# Cannot import bootstrap in nuxt vue component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I can't import bootstrap in any vue component (using latest nuxtjs). I get :

[image]

My (simple) component is :

```
<template>
  <h1>Empty index page</h1>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/src/modal'

export default {}
</script>

<style></style>
```

I am really stuck. Do you have any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: Use bootstrap-vue, here is the doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/#nuxtjs-module

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap-vue, they fix a lot of issues and their tree-shacking works amazing.

your code will be

```js
<template>
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button> 
  <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue" >
    <h1>Empty index page</h1>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
  import { BModal, BButton } from 'bootstrap-vue'

  export default {
    name: "Modal Component",
    components: {
      'b-modal': BModal,
      'b-button': BButton
    }
  }
</script>

<style></style>
```

more info in the [bootstrap-vue guide](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal)