# nodejs import module is not working as expecting,

Tags: node.js, babeljs, package.json

I have the following structure.

```
node_modules
src
 - app.js
 - newrelic.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

In newrelic.js  its a simple class

```
const axios = require('axios')

export default class Newrelic {
  static getName() {
   return 'Hello;
  }
}
```

in app.js

```
import Newrelic from "./newrelic";
console.log(Newrelic.getName())
```

When I run node src/app.js Sadly I receive

```
import Newrelic from "./newrelic";
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

What do I need to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json` add the field `"type": "module"` and your code will work.

More info here:
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a very frequent question, when you deal with old packages. For example, it works with 'express-handlebars' v.6.x too.
Adding to file package.json the field "type": "module" resolves a similar conflict.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).