# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - Danger System with React

Tags: ecmascript-6, file-import

I am using [Danger JS](https://github.com/danger/danger-js) with React app created using `create-react-app`. So I have a `dangerfile.js` like below in the `Root directory` of the project.

```
import {message, danger} from "danger"

const modifiedMD = danger.git.modified_files.join("- ")
message("Changed Files in this PR: \n - " + modifiedMD)
```

The import works in this case. But when I am trying to install a plugin like [danger-plugin-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/danger-plugin-eslint) the import doesn't work.

```
  import {message, danger} from "danger"
  import eslint from 'danger-plugin-eslint'
  
  const modifiedMD = danger.git.modified_files.join("- ")
  message("Changed Files in this PR: \n - " + modifiedMD)

  eslint()
```

The error says -

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am new to react. Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58212338/2504407

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you using babel and how you created the project? The problem is that your project is not identifying the import keyword this could be a babel problem.

Comment: @Md.MoshfiqurRahmanRony React app created using create-react-app. And the dangerfile.js is in the project root.

Comment: So my guess is babel is missing to parse your danger.js. Try using raw JS like require instead of import.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error today and as I didn't found the solution anywhere, here one solution that worked for me: just drop the `import` or `requirement` lines.

Just this should work fine

```
const modifiedMD = danger.git.modified_files.join("- ")
message("Changed Files in this PR: \n - " + modifiedMD)
```