# ElectronJS: Renderer can't resolve module require("./index.js") over HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, electron

I have my folder structure set up like this:

```
assets/
  logo.png
  other_web_assets.png
electron/
  node_modules
  main.js
  package-lock.json
  package.json
src/
  index.js
  otherJavascriptFiles.js
index.html
style.css
```

The reason I've separated ElectronJS from the website is that the website is intended to be served via HTTP (it's not supposed to work without Electron though, I only need the HTTP protocol for Firebase Authentication). Currently I'm serving `index.html` via the LiveServer VSCode extension on port 5500.

In my `index.html` I'm using `require("./src/index.js")` to load `index.js`, and in the `index.js` file I use `require` to communicate with the other javascript files and other node modules.

However, the `require("./src/index.js")` doesn't work from `index.html`, I always get the error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './src/index'` in the dev tools console.
I've tried importing `index.js` with `<script src="./src/index.js"></script>`, but that results in the same error, with a different javascript file that my `index.js` tries to import using `require`.

I can however require normal node modules (for example `require("request")`) without any errors.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import functions from a js file I use

```
import {functionName} from 'path to js file where function is defined'
```

I use Require for pictures, etc. but not for js files.

I suggest you to use import. Also, define the functions you need to import into other files using the word export

Comment: I just gave this a try, now there's an error in the dev tools saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I only had to change my exports from "exports.variable = variable" to "export default { variable }"