# import array from different file in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

array_test.js:

```
export const output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

index.js:

```
import output from "./array_test.js"
```

Error:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am trying to export my array from `array_test.js` to `index.js`, but I don't know why I am getting this error. How can I fix this error?

Comment: [will this help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import) ?

Comment: 1. You probably need to enable modules for your setup. Where are you using this? Browser? Node? I assume Node - which is the version? 2. You either need to do `export default` or instead to `import { output }` - right now the export and import are mismatched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 0):

Depending in what environment you are you need to change some things.

When you have an .js file that exports something like this:

```
//array.js
export const output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Inside your HTML file you need to add the type `module` and then you can import it

```
<script type="module">
    import { output } from "./array_test.js"
</script>
```

Also, you do a named export. That means you need to import it exactly by its name again.

In case you use node.js you would need to go to your `package.json` and add a new property to it:

`"type": "module"`

After this it should work.
Depending on what version your node.js has you would need to add the `--experimental-modules` flag when you execute it like: `node index.js --experimental-modules`