# I cannot use import/export nor require

Tags: javascript, html, import, export, require

When I use require I get ReferenceError: require is not defined and when I use import/export I get SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Is it maybe because I am trying to use this commands on JavaScript file that is connected to HTML file? Because when I use this commands in my server.js file (that is not connected to any HTML file) I can normally use require.

If so, how can I overcome this problem. I got JavaScript file connected with each HTML page and I want to import functions to thoose scripts to make code clearer.

Comment: use tag script with src in html

Comment: @vturkovic can you show a little piece of what you do in html - why do you need import or require. Best way - keep separately html and js

Comment: There are some rules that you must follow when using them in a web browser, this might help you  ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: As far as I know Javascript doesn't have import, export or require. You need to add `<script src="/path/to/your/javascript.js"></script>` to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know import and export only work with modules. in order to overcome that, you can use **Webpack** for that, which you can basically use export and import between files, and webpack bundles them all together in one file. this is a tutorial for beginners on how to set it up if you are interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzdEpgONurw&ab_channel=DesignCourse