# Why is my <audio></audio> element not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Hi so I have been developing an audio player app with HTML and JavaScript. I'm trying to embed an audio tag inside of my html file, following the tutorial from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZL9gVwxO-U&list=WL&index=1&t=452s).

And I have followed it till 5:00, and inside the audioPlayer div, it should've shown the audio element we have embedded using the JS. Like this from the video:
[image]

But in my case the div tag won't expand. Means the audio tag is not embedded right?
[image]

And show an error like the following:
[image]

These are my codes:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
    <title>Javascript Audio Player</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="audioPlayer"></div>
    <script src="../static/common-js/player.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

player.js:

```
import AudioPlayer from './audioPlayer';

const audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer('./audioPlayer', [
    {url: '../music/rainfall.mp3', name: 'Alleviating Rainfall'},

]);
```

AudioPlayer.js:

```
export default class AudioPlayer {
    constructor(selector = '.audioPlayer', audio = []) {
        this.playerElem = document.querySelector(selector);
        this.audio = audio;
        this.currentAudio = null;
        this.createPlayerElements();
    }
}
```

and here is my file directory:
[image]

I just want to know where did I go wrong. Thank you in advance! I'd appreciate every help.

Comment: The screenshot of the error you have is pretty self explanatory, and I believe that is, in part, why you are having issues. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import).

Comment: have you set width and height?

Comment: @ioalft: I will help you if no one does. But I need some time. I am a bit occupied with my portfolio project. My interview  assignment deadline is approaching. Just give me 1 hour. I will help you in case no body helps :) Stay Blessed

Comment: thanks @ImranRafiqRather good luck for your project!

Comment: @ioalft: Getting error while using npm run serve