# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-pagination'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pagination

I already installed react-pagination using below command:-

```
npm i react-bootstrap-4-pagination
```

My Code:-

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Pagination from 'react-pagination';


let paginationConfig = {
  totalPages: 22,
  currentPage: 15,
  showMax: 5,
  size: "lg",
  threeDots: true,
  prevNext: true,
  href: 'https://example.com/items?page=*', // * will be replaced by the page number
  pageOneHref: 'https://example.com/items',
  borderColor: 'red',
  activeBorderColor: 'black',
  activeBgColor: 'grey',
  disabledBgColor: 'red',
  activeColor: 'red',
  color: 'purple',
  disabledColor: 'green',
  circle: true,
  shadow: true
};




   <Pagination
        threeDots
        totalPages={22}
        currentPage={15}
        showMax={7}
        prevNext
        activeBgColor="#18eaca"
        activeBorderColor="#7bc9c9"
      />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: I guess this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import
and also make sure you have file extension jsx | tsx instead of .js | .ts for component files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the package documentation, as the import is stated incorrectly [here at official page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-4-pagination).

```
import Pagination from 'react-pagination';
```

above import statement should be

```
import Pagination from "react-bootstrap-4-pagination";
```

But it is stated correctly in the live demo provided at package officital page at codesandbox.io here [code for live demo provided in official docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-4-pagination-12efe)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install react-pagination:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

and import like this:

```
import Pagination from 'react-bootstrap/Pagination'
```