# Error with importing module on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, module

I have been trying to import this module which returns live stock prices. Each time I try to import it I get an error from google saying I cannot "use import statement outside of module."

Html Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="JSpractice.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="p">hello world</p>
    <button type="button" >Hello world</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
import { getCurrentPrice } from './modules/yahoo-stock-prices';

document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = getCurrentPrice("AAPL");
```

Google Error:

```
JSpractice.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Any advice?

Comment: possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: @alewis729 I have tried those solutions already. :(