# How to fix "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to put together my first React Typescript JSX component npm package.

I copied working code from a CRA TypeScript project to an empty folder and added the following `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`.

## package.json

```json
{
  "name": "react-hashlink",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "React hash link",
  "main": "lib/HashLink.js",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "hash",
    "link"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
    "npm-check-updates": "^10.2.5",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "code": "tsc -w",
    "build": "rm -fr lib/*; tsc",
    "ncu": "ncu -u"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "endOfLine": "lf",
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": false,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

When I import `react-hashlink` using `npm link` and `npm link react-hashlink` in a project, the following error is thrown.

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I am likely missing something. Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: Thanks for helping out @OrAssayag. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `"module": "commonjs"` and `"target": "esnext"` did the job!

Comment: "module": "commonjs" and "target": "esnext" did not work for me