# Error While Importing Axios: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

While importing Axios I am facing an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I am importing Axios like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

[this image shows my javascript file strucure where i hava imported axios which i installed through npm i axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgvkb.png)

[this is how i import axios in main js file that is shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b01EU.png)

[this is  my project header ,where i have included my js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEMha.png)

Comment: try `const axios = require('axios').default;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: @NotABot i am using  it in the front end  , main.js file

Comment: @afnan Please check the link I mentioned in the previous comment, you will get some help from there

Comment: we just don't know enough. is your main.js file an ES module? are you working within a framework that compiles and bundles your code?

Comment: @Nnay  actually i was watching a tutotial and they included  import axios , i did the same  then after some research i foud i had to include type="module"  but even now  its now working .. i have never workied with importing stuff before ....
    <script  type="module"  src="/main.js"></script>

Comment: @Nnay now i am facing this error  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: The browser doesn't magically load npm packages. If you are using modules in the browser then you have to use URLs as import specifier.

Comment: @FelixKling  can you please explain your ans ?

Comment: `'axios'` is not a URL. If you want to import a JavaScript module in the browser you have to tell the browser where to load it from, which requires a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you using this statement? If you are you using it on backend then you should use

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

if you are getting it on frontend then you may not have installed the package axios. To install it run

```
npm i axios
```

Comment: even on the frontend it depends on whether or not it's used in an ES module. `import` won't work otherwise

Comment: Yes, the question is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: @Ghulam Ghous  i have already installed  the dependency

Comment: @afnan can you please elaborate on your question and also the folder structure a bit. I am not able to fully understand the question.

Comment: @GhulamGhous bro i have included  some images , that might help you understand my questions thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-axios-in-vanilla-javascript-2dbf176e08d4 visit this link, this will solve your issue. You have to include the URL for fetching axios in browser.