# Using JavaScript class in another .js file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have declare a class in a FoodItem.js file like

```
export default class FoodItem {

   constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   methodOne() {
      //statement
   }

}
```

And then in index.js file (same directory as FoodItem.js) I do an import like

```
import FoodItem from './FoodItem';
```

When I run it, I got an error

> Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Can anyone tell what is wrong with the export/import syntax?

Comment: Does it work when you attempt to do the same thing with `require`?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the index.js. Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Answer (score 0):

Add a type="module" to your script tag.

**Previous code:**

```
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use imports inside HTML, make sure the `type` attribute is set to `module`, like this:

```html
<sciprt type="module">
    import something from "./some-file.js";
</script>
```

Also, don't forget to include the path to the file relative to the current file, **including the `.js` extension**, if necessary.