# How to module.export a value defined inside an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have the below code and want to export the `handler` using `module.exports.handler`. Since `start()` is an **async function** and the **handler is defined inside** of it, I can't export it properly by using the below code. I tried using **top-level await** for start() and [got an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126382/why-top-level-package-jsons-type-module-is-affecting-the-packages-inside-n). Can I know another way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
//index.ts

import serverless from 'serverless-http';

let handler;
const start = async (): Promise<void> => {
    
    //some function calls with await

    const server = express();
    //server.use()

    handler = serverless(server);
};

start().then(() => {
    console.log(handler) //[AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
});
console.log(handler) //undefined

module.exports.handler = handler;
```

Btw, I need to use `handler` in my `serverless.yml`

```
service: rest-server
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-1
  environment: ${file(serverless.env.yml)
  stage: dev
  memorySize: 128
functions:
  h5p:
    handler: src/index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
```

Comment: why not export the `start` function and call `start` where you need to the `handler`?

Comment: you can't export a value that isn't available immediately - you can export a Promise though ... `module.exports.handlerPromise = start()` ...

Comment: @JaromandaX In general, yes, but I suppose serverless won't like that

Comment: @Bergi - yeah, I don't know `serverless` :p

Comment: @Bergi according to their [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-http) serverless allows the handler to be async, so one can use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new handler, that waits until starting is done, and then calls the original handler. This only requires, that the exported handler function is allowed to be async.

```js
const finishedStarting = start()

module.exports.handler = (...args) => finishedStarting.then(() => handler(...args));
```

Comment: Don't make it so complicated with managing `startingCallbacks` yourself. Just use `const handlerPromise = start(); module.export.handler = async (...args) { const handler = await handlerPromise; return handler(...args); };` (or `….handler = (...args) => handlerPromise.then(handler => handler(...args));` which is even a bit shorter)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I didn't know that one could use `.then` multiple times on a Promise

Comment: I tested this solution with a couple of endpoints. Seems like finally I can go with this. Thanks for your time @A_A :)