# Unable to initialize firebase using JS 9 version

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to learn Firebase as I am new to it. I am trying to follow the documentation. However, the console always shows up some error.

```
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="signIn()">Login With Google</button>
<script src="js/firebase.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

firebase.js

```
// FIREBASE INITIALIZATION
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

custom.js

```
async function signIn(){
  // Sign in using a popup.
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.addScope('profile');
  provider.addScope('email');
  const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

  // The signed-in user info.
  const user = result.user;
  // This gives you a Google Access Token.
  const credential = provider.credentialFromResult(auth, result);
  const token = credential.accessToken;

}
```

When I click on the button this error shows up

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: GoogleAuthProvider is not defined
```

Checked my codes again and again but unable to locate error. What should I do now?

Comment: async function signIn()

Comment: @samthecodingman oh yes how could I miss that !!!!!!!!!! that solves the first error. Now clicking on button returns this `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: GoogleAuthProvider is not defined` but you can see I did import `GoogleAuthProvider ` in `firebase.js`

Comment: Modules are completely isolated in the browser and won't attach things to `window` or `global`. You'll need to add `type="module"` to each script tag and import what you need in each file. While you could continue to use modules as they are, you should look into a build tool like Webpack or Rollup to compile your application for use in browsers.

Comment: Currently for learning purpose I intend to use only CDN... Once I get a good hang of it I will definitely consider your suggestions. For the first part of your comment, you can see in the HTML part that I have already added `type="module"` in the `firebase.js`.

Comment: While you import it in `firebase.js` (which is a module), `custom.js` must also be a module AND you need to import `GoogleAuthProvider` provider there too. If you want to tinker in the browser, you'll need to use a way to expose the module's contents to the regular browser like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69231031/3068190).