# Why are the functions not triggering?

Tags: javascript, firebase, animation, simplemodal

https://github.com/DaCodeWiz/advanced-ePortfolio
https://dacodewiz.github.io/advanced-ePortfolio/#
^Link to repo and build.
I added Firebase and I think it messed up the Javascript but I don't know what went wrong since all the HTML and CSS remained the same.

```
function toggleModal() {
if (isModalOpen){
    isModalOpen = false;
    return document.body.classList.remove("modal--open");
}
isModalOpen = true;
// toggle modal
document.body.classList += " modal--open";
}


// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: #
};
```

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

Comment: I changed the appId and measurementId because privacy reasons

Comment: you didn't need to include the apiKey as is.  You could've just  left it at ```<key>``` and it would be sufficient.

Comment: Firebase V9+ is meant to be built using a bundler before deployment. If you want to use the library without the build step, you need to wrap your application code in `<script type="module"></script>` and use a CDN for grapping the modules. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69230383/3068190) for details.