# React w/ Firebase: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

I've been following [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/) tutorial for setting up firebase authentication with React.
Unfortunately I already run into problems when trying to set up the firebase configuration. I have the following `firebase.js` file, just like in the tutorial:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // I removed the configuration for security purposes
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const database = firebase.database();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
}
```

I start up the React app and Google Chrome (!!!NOT REACT!!!) gives me the following error in the console:
[image]
Alright then, let's take a look at what piece of code that is.
[image]
As you can see, this is not an error from my code, but from the firebase code. This is in fact the code from the file at `/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js`. I tried reinstalling the firebase npm package multiple times, I even deleted the node modules folder, but it seems like this is intended.
I looked at my own code in Google Chrome to see what happened to the import statements that I used, and as you can see they've been changed to webpack require statements, while the firebase code hasn't changed
[image]
Any help as to why this error occurs, and/or how I can fix it is highly apprechiated!

## Update

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-app-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.9",
    "electron-winstaller": "^5.0.0",
    "foreman": "^2.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.4",
    "firebase": "^8.7.0",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1"
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "src/electron-starter.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "dev": "nf start -p 3000"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you had  a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: Try importing just `firebase` instead of `firebase/app` and see what happens.

Comment: @HarshithL that leads to the same problem, but this time the code is from `/node_modules/firebase/dist/index.esm.js`

Comment: @iLuvLogix Those answers are mainly for importing firebase with script tags, but the answers for npm modules didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: I updated the question to include my package.json

Comment: Please post text, not pictures of text.

Comment: @iLuvLogix Yes I have tried that and it didn't work

Comment: seems like some ES/environment issue..

Comment: @iLuvLogix I am using WSL for this project and have just tried running it with powershell, so windows only. Unfortunately that didn't change anything either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by simply downgrading my firebase version to version `7.8.2`, the same version that the tutorial uses. It feels like this shouldn't be the way to solve this issue, but it works.