# It give me error while importing axios from node module

Tags: javascript, axios

I have installed axios via npm and try to import axios to my front end script file.

The error which i am facing is

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

**This is my app.js file**

```
import axios from 'axios';

function updateRecipt(items) {
    axios.post('/update-reciept',items).then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

**Note**:I also change "type":"tag" to "type":"module" in axios package.json  and import statement to const axios = require("../../node_module/axios"). but it doesnot work for me

Answer (score 3):

You are using CommonJS.
To import axios you could do

```
const axios = require("axios");
```

Instead if you want to use ES Modules,
you need to go to `package.json`and add `"type": "module",` (you could also add `"type": "commonjs",` to use explicitly CommonJS)

Comment: I have change type to "type":"commonjs" but it give me another error that require is not defined

Comment: Are you testing this in a browser? In this case, require won't work as it doesn't exisist on that enviorment

Comment: Yes sir i want to console data in chrome

Comment: In this case, you should use ES Modules, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). Also [this](https://electerious.medium.com/from-commonjs-to-es-modules-how-to-modernize-your-node-js-app-ad8cdd4fb662) could help

Comment: Not working sir. It says cannot  use import statement outside a module

Comment: try adding ```"type":"module"``` to the importing script. This meaning:
```<script type="module" src="path/to/script"></script>```

Comment: Sir how i can write this script tag in js file ?

Comment: I ment in the HTML file where you are importing the script

Comment: Same error sir. I tried this in html file and i write my axios call statement bellow your script statement but it give me same error

Comment: This should help [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the es6 syntax instead of the commonJS. Try using this

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

If you want to use es6, you'll need something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: I also tried this but it says require is not defined

Comment: add or change the line `"type": "commonjs"` in your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that in another file, then do this:

```js
const axios = require('your_file.js');
```

then go back to your file, and add:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
module.exports = axios
```

Comment: Couldn't understand sir. what are you saying ?

Comment: create a second file, and paste your code in there, with `module.exports = axios;` at the end.
then go to your main file, and add `const axios = require('your_file.js')`

Answer (score 0):

Ive solved this problem by using babel.

create a .babelrc file with

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

add this to devDependancies in package.json

```
 "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
```

add this to jest.config.cjs

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
};
```