# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module -> pupa package

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

The package that has the issues is pupa

I am importing it as

```js
import pupa from 'pupa'
```

I am running the tests using jest and I have changed my jest.config file

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `node_modules/(?!(@pupa)/)`,
  ],
```

On my test file as well I am importing this on the top of my file

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

Comment: Unit testing is usually done in node, why are you doing it in the browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)