# facing issue in react js showing "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './Navigation';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Navigation/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

showing syntax error Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: This thread might have solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: Just fyi, stack trace should be the first thing to share, helps in tracking the exact place from which the error comes

Answer (score 0):

change `import './Navigation';` to `import Navigation from './Navigation';`

if `Navigation` is not `default export` then change it to `import { Navigation } from './Navigation';`

Comment: i did but still facing error in console

Comment: can you post your Navigation.js code ?

Comment: yes but its little l9ong

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading this file from your `HTML` you will need to set the `type` to `module` on the script tag.

Like: `<script type="module" src="/path/to/file.js"></script">`

Comment: still not working