# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (Type Script)

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

so im having this issue with me type script import

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is this during TS compilation or running your JS file? If during execution, are you using Node or browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)