# Cannot use import statement outside a module - im trying to declare imports in my nodejs server but I cant

Tags: node.js, express, import

I have a simple example :

```
import { fetch } from 'node-fetch';
import {express} from 'express';

const app = express();


const PORT = 3000
const RANDOM_DOGS_ENDPOINT = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random';

app.get('/get_dog', async  (req, res) => {

    const result = await fetch(RANDOM_DOGS_ENDPOINT);
    res.json(result)
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port  ${PORT} ..`)
});
```

My objetive is creating a server to provide a free endpoint :
https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random . Then, on my front call my own endpoint which is calling this one.

Im trying to use `fetch` module to **http request** , I found this package (`node-fetch`) to apply that. But Im facing problems about **how to import package I have installed on my node_modules**.

Welf, I usually to import like this :

```
const express = require('express')
...
```

And I love it, but on this case, to use fetch  I have watched that i need to use this other way to import, first problem after that was i had imports by two ways : `import {foo} from bar` and `const express = require..` . So I found by SO that is a problem mixing this two ways.. Ok then all imports now will be by `import {foo} from bar` then Im facing problems again, my currently problem is :

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Then... What is the point if I cant import as 'import' and either 'require..'

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655153/7628937)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your example and it works fine. I usually employ node-fetch using require but I am using the 2.6.7 version. I think you can employ freely es6 and es5 both with node-fetch@[2.6.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch/v/2.6.7) and [latest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch/).
If you want to use es6 to import node-fetch do not use single module import:

```
import { fetch } from 'node-fetch';
```

But import the entire moduele

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

In conclusion, node does not support natively es6 for importing modules you have to configure it correctely, check out [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/) for better understanding.