# swiperjs Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, npm, import, swiper.js

I am trying to use swiper from swiperjs.com on my website. I installed node and added swiper as a dependency with the `npm install swiper` command. I created a `swiper.js` file where I am trying to import swiper:

```
import Swiper from "swiper";
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper");
```

In the `head` of my HTML I added this line to load the `swiper.js` file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/js/swiper.js"></script>`

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sasstheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "sass --watch src/scss/style.scss style.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.49.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "swiper": "^8.0.7"
  }
}
```

When I load the page I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: You have to bundle it with some bundler (ex.: _Webpack_ or _Vite_) or use bundled version (_swiper-bundle.min.js_).

Comment: `import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';` and `import Swiper from "swiper-bundle.min.js";` gives me the same error. @Jax-p

Comment: Yes. Because you are still using [import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import). Use some bundler or include your script as module (modern browsers only) or include swiper script solo `<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js">`.

Comment: I used parcel as the bunder as you suggested and the `import` works fine now, thank you! However I am confused now what is the point of using a bundler to import the script and style and then load these in the HTML instead of just including it from swipers CDN. Is there any benefit of using a bundler?