# Doing imports in VS Code / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do an import from one file to another in VSCode. My two files are as follows:

```
// file2.js
const Name1 = "Bob";
const Name2 = "Sarah";

class Person {
    constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
    greet() { console.log('Hello,', this.name); }
}

export {Name1, Name2, Person};
```

```
// file1.js
import { Name1, Name2, Person } from "./file2.js"
p = new Person(Name1);
p.greet();
```

However, I get the following error from VSCode / Node:

> import { Name1, Name2, Person } from "./file2.js" 
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

What does that mean exactly (why isn't the file considered a module?), and how would I properly fix that to do a valid import?

Comment: Duplicate ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone where is the package.json file defined?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example:

```
// folder structure
test_import/
  - file1.js
  - file2.js
  - package.json
```

```
// file1.js
import { Name1, Name2, Person } from "./file2.js"
let p = new Person(Name1);
p.greet();
```

```
// file2.js
const Name1 = "Bob";
const Name2 = "Sarah";

class Person {
    constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
    greet() { console.log('Hello,', this.name); }
}

export {Name1, Name2, Person};
```

```
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

In other words, just add a json file named `package.json` -- or do `npm init` with the`"type": "module"` entry.

Answer (score 0):

it's a problem because of using require or import as your style, as well as how you invoke your node/js.  if you want to use imports, then you need to have your JS code in .mjs files, change your config.json to include `"type": "module"`, and then you can do this.  or simply use require if you prefer not to go the EMCMA6 route.