# Facing problem on importing express from express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I am working on MERN app and while importing express it is showing error
it shows `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
my code is

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('this is homepage')
})

app.listen( port ,()=>{
    console.log('server is running at port number 3000')
});
```

Comment: is it this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: Replace `import express from 'express';` with `const express = require('express');`

Comment: Node with the extension `.js` will use common.js loader, eg. `require`, if you want to use ES loader, you can rename the file extension to `.mjs`.   There are other subtle differences between ES & CommonJS, so you might want check those out..  eg, with ES you won't get the very useful  `__dirname`, but there are workarounds for this.

Answer (score 12):

`import` and `export` are ES6 syntax.
To enable ES6 modules in your NodeJS app add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file.
Alternatively you can use the `.mjs` extension for your files.
Otherwise node defaults to the CommonJS module loader which uses `require` and `module.exports` syntax.

ES6 module support is stable in Node v12 and above, and in experimental in v9 - v11, requiring passing the `--experimental-module` flag.

Node.js documentation: [Modules: ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules)

Answer (score 5):

Use [namespace import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#namespace_import)

```
import * as express from "express";
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use:

```
const express = require('express');
```

or just write:

`"type": "module"`, in your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

add such line in your package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i always had used babel, with babel you can use both import and require
in my case the error appears because use import and require. my solutions is:

step 1: install babel. you should run this command: `

> npm i -D @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env

`

step 2:say to babel that execute app.js or index.js. in file package.json in section
"scripts" add this follow lines:

```
"devbabel": "nodemon app.js --exec babel-node",
"start": "babel-node app.js --exec"
```

step 3: create new file of type babel with name ".babelrc" with follow content:

> { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }

done. its working for me in version 20 node.

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
const e = require('express')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This just repeats an existing answer.

Comment: The question is how to use import (ES6) and your answer is to exact opposite