# Next-Auth Firebase Implementation for Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, next-auth

Would like to use #next-auth for authentication with Google provider and use firebase as the storage for user and session data. Getting the following error , while implementing the setup.

**Error**

```
Server Error
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The firebase.config.js looks like the following.

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = getApps.length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);

const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, db, storage };
```

The solution, I tried but not having success.

- **Changing the .js extension to .mjs and .cjs**
- **Changing version of firebase from 9 to 11 and vice versa**

**System configuration**

```
system:
    OS: macOS 12.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8257U CPU @ 1.40GHz
    Memory: 135.65 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.11.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 105.0.5195.125
    Safari: 16.0
  npmPackages:
    next: 12.3.1 => 12.3.1 
    next-auth: ^4.13.0 => 4.13.0 
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 


  npmPackages:
    @next-auth/firebase-adapter: ^1.0.2 => 1.0.2
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899085/6803592

Comment: Thanks, Olaf. How do you implement the "script" tag in nextjs. Dont want to add unnecessary scripts that are not on the official nextjs docs.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in #next-auth/firestoreadaptor for v1.0.2. Got confirmation from the awesome devs working on it.

**Please use v1.0.1 for now. Stay tuned to their message board.**

Prefered for now.

```
@next-auth/firebase-adapter: 1.0.1
```