# import declarations may only appear at top level of a module: importing a .js file which import node_modules

Tags: javascript, import

I'm just trying to prototype something quickly (typically use React), dumping some JS code into an html file. I don't get why this import doesn't work.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>three.js app</title>
    <h1>Some app:</h1>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/threeCode.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

Then my JS code would live here:

threeCode.js:

```
import  * as THREE from './three';

console.log("hellow world")
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

But then I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Three is a node module (three.js) via npm install.

EDIT: serving using `http-server -o -cors`

Comment: set type="module" on <script> tag

Comment: but threeCode.js is just my js file, not a module?

Comment: You are using it like a module since you are importing other modules. Therefore it needs to be marked as a module when included on your page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: If I put type="module", I now get an mime-type error trying to server threeCode.js. I should add I'm using npm http-server to server: http-server -o -cors

Comment: Going through the thread now. Maybe - through there's a lot of stuff in there.