# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, npm, module, syntax-error, puppeteer

Hello I keep trying to run the puppeteer test but keep getting this issue. Please help thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEsMC.png)
code:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://developers.google.com/web/');

  // Type into search box.
  await page.type('.devsite-search-field', 'Headless Chrome');

  // Wait for suggest overlay to appear and click "show all results".
  const allResultsSelector = '.devsite-suggest-all-results';
  await page.waitForSelector(allResultsSelector);
  await page.click(allResultsSelector);

  // Wait for the results page to load and display the results.
  const resultsSelector = '.gsc-results .gs-title';
  await page.waitForSelector(resultsSelector);

  // Extract the results from the page.
  const links = await page.evaluate(resultsSelector => {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll(resultsSelector)].map(anchor => {
      const title = anchor.textContent.split('|')[0].trim();
      return `${title} - ${anchor.href}`;
    });
  }, resultsSelector);

  // Print all the files.
  console.log(links.join('\n'));

  await browser.close();
})();
```

error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I have tried reinstalling node js and npm but nothing has worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 3):

```
{
 "name": "my-app",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "type": "module",
 "scripts": { ...
 },
   ...
 }
```

Add type:module in your package.json file or install the latest Nodejs