# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, import, syntax-error

I'm trying to deploy my web app into heroku and I have been getting this problem since I added the "emailjs" module. Before that my deploy worked well and now im getting the same problem every time. to matter what i try.[Heroku logs results after trying to deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2hHt.png)

**this is my code in index.js:
**
`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

`

The thing is: when i change the "import" to "require" the code throws me more and more errors.

**this is my packakge.json:

**

```
{
  "name": "chipsi-puntos",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Im deployng thru heroku using github. If you have any advice, ill be so thankfull <3

I've tried all the solutions that are written here: ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

I also tried to switch the "import" to "require" and didnt work.

I expect my code to do well on heroku.

Pd: it works 100% OK on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you're using import statements you should have "type": "module" in the package.json file. Since you don't have it, you should use require statements instead. If I were you, I'll try adding `"type": "module"` to the package.json. You could also try invoking the flag: `--experimental-modules`

More info on that can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for sharing, but i still have the problem, even after adding the `"type": "module"` but now is different. Now i get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` `<React.StrictMode>
2022-12-13T04:25:06.762207+00:00 app[web.1]: ^`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "Name of your app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

Change Your index.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for sharing, but i still have the problem, even after adding the "type": "module" but now is different. Now i get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' <React.StrictMode> 2022-12-13T04:25:06.762207+00:00 app[web.1]: ^

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you try updating your index file?