# run javascript as module with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I apologize if this is a basic question. I am new to JavaScript and couldn't find an answer after searching.

I am trying to run the file f1.js:

```
import abc from "./f2.js"

console.log(abc);
```

The f2.js looks like this:

```
export let abc = 1
```

When I tried to run f1.js using command `node f1.js`, it throw an error:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I have seen other people run multiple files in html and specify type = module. My question is, can I do this without an html file and instead run it using node?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` which you can build yourself, or have npm do it with `npm init` although you'll probably have to edit the file and add that line yourself.

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: `import {abc} from "./f2.js"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Node.js has two module systems: CommonJS modules and ECMAScript modules.
>
> Authors can tell Node.js to use the ECMAScript modules loader via the .mjs file extension, the package.json "type" field, or the --input-type flag. Outside of those cases, Node.js will use the CommonJS module loader.

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

To use import/export statements in node.js you have to use ECMAScript modules loader.
In your example the simplest solution is to change the file extension to ".mjs".
Additionally, as [@Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad) have mentioned in the comments, you have to use brackets around "abc":

```
import {abc} from "./f2.js"
```