# Why isn't my JQuery working in Ruby on Rails Application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just started a new project and struggling to get my JQuery working. I created a new file: *app/javascript/menu.js* after reading that I shouldn't be including JS in */javascript/application.js*

And filled it with some basic JQuery to test:

```
$(".star").on('click', function () {
    $(".star").hide();
});
```

My *application.js* contains this after also reading a lot about having to include these files:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

//= require jquery
//= require menu.js
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

My *app/views/home/index.html.erb* contains this:

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
<div class="star" style="color:yellow">star</div>
```

Based on other solutions I have tried putting:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

in the head of my *layout/application.html.erb* file

And also have the JQuery Gem included in my *Gemfile* and ran bundle install:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

A few JS related **errors** in console being shown (not sure which are relevant):

*A preload for 'http://localhost:3000/assets/application-c6cfeddf2cc82767c591b13a28614b8f0f939b097ea8471155ef803809350558.js' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute.*

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*

*The resource http://localhost:3000/assets/es-module-shims.min-d89e73202ec09dede55fb74115af9c5f9f2bb965433de1c2446e1faa6dac2470.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.*

*DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: Fetch through target failed: Frame not found; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME*

Comment: what error are you seeing in the browser console?

Comment: @dbugger Looks like I have a few JS related errors showing. Have added to original post. Thanks

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: Solution was to include:    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> in the <head> of every page. I thought me installing the Jquery Gem meant I wouldn't need to do this?

Comment: That is a very bad sanity test. That event handler will only work if the `.star` elements are present and ready when the script is executed. It won't work for elements inserted dynamically (for example by Turbo/Turbolinks). Use `$(document).on('click', '.star', function(){ $(this).hide(); })`

Comment: so you're using importmaps, but also `jquery-rails` for some reason. if you have to do it this way, `//= require` directives must come first. i assume you also have `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` which imports `application.js` already. can't use `javascript_include_tag`, sprockets doesn't process `import` statements and they can only be used inside `<script type="module">` tags. a lot of rails 6 things don't apply to rails 7. some new things you have to look up: "importmap-rails", "jsbundling-rails", "cssbundling-rails", "turbo-rails" (no turbolinks)