# Import modules with eval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import

Is it possible to import modules with 'import' inside an eval in JavaScript?

Something like this idk

```
let test = index;

eval(`import { a } from './${test}.js'`);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `const { a } = await import('./${test}.js')`?

Comment: You could try using the dynamic version, `import()`, but I don't see why you would need to.

Comment: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import