# Why npm start not working after npm init?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import

I have initiated a new project with NPM :
`npm init`

I have installed the socket.io-client package.

**package.json:**

`{ "name": "client", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "", "main": "script.js", "scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }, "author": "", "license": "ISC", "dependencies": { "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4" } }`

**script.js:**

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')

socket.on('connect', () => {

console.log('Hello - ' + socket.id)
})
```

The error I get:

`npm ERR! Missing script: "start"`

I have added the start command to package.json:

`"start": "node script.js"`

Now I get:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I have tried adding start command, and did not worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of these:

- Add `type="module"` to whereever you import your script.
- Add "`type": "module"` to your `package.json` file.

See more here: ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. Duplicates are closed.

Comment: @kaligouri . I have added type module into my package.json file as you wrote. Now I have an another error. In my script.js there is document.getElementById function which trying to get an element in my index.html. Now I get: 
ReferenceError: document is not defined. 

I have added my script.js into my index.html with script tag. I think now script.js does not sees my index.html, how can I fix that?
I