# Firebase hosting - storage - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, firebase, hosting

This is the error I'm getting on the website that I host:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've spent the last few hours scanning the internet and the stack with so many questions like this but none solved my issue.

#### JavaScipt Code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; // The error is getting on this line already
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
```

#### In the `index.html` body:

```html
<script src="js/get_firebase_data.js"></script>
```

I also tried putting `type="module"` in the script but still no luck.

#### My `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "name": "sols",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run bundle && npm run minify",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "DIF",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

---

### Update:

Someone suggested that this answers my question: ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import), but it does not, I just tried **all** of the suggested answer in that question plus many other questions I found, but still no luck in finding a solution for me.

If you need me to provide any more information about my situation, please comment and I shall provide it for you shortly, thank you.