# node.js Module Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I maintain [a node.js library](https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect) and I [tried to add](https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect/pull/2/files) the following piece of code:

```js
const curlirize = require('axios-curlirize')
```

And I get the following error (on `node` version `19.x`): `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880) on SO and I [tried adding](https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect/pull/2/commits/15a8bb87a57660084bfa86df7ee6982a06db0cc3) `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` and that did not work either.

Although master build is [passing](https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect/actions?query=branch%3Amain), PR build is [failing](https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect/actions?query=branch%3Acurlirize). What am I doing wrong? I looked at [another library](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afreearhey%2Fiptv-checker%20curlirize&type=code) with the same package structure as me that uses `require('axios-curlirize')` and that library works just fine!

PS: I actually do not want `type: module` since I need it to be CJS - but I want to understand why [other code works](https://github.com/search?q=require%20axios-curlirize%20language%3AJavaScript&type=code&l=JavaScript) with the `require` works but not mine!

Comment: 2.0.0 - Uses ES Native Modules
1.3.7 - Uses CommonJS Modules . after looking at the github

Comment: also with type:module you need to use import syntax

Comment: @cmgchess: I don't think that's the issue. I tried using 1.3.7 here: https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect/pull/2/commits/70033ac40c602a51a3b0b4fbcdab9934610fb1ec

Same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using 2.0.0 with type:module and import syntax. or 13.7 and require syntax and remove type:module from package json

Comment: > also with type:module you need to use import syntax – 

Ok so how do I fix this? I tried 1.3.7 and/or removing the `type:module` - I still get same build error. When I see other usages in Github, it uses the `require` style: https://github.com/search?q=curlirize+language%3AJavaScript&type=code&l=JavaScript

Comment: As I said, I cannot use the import syntax. The `require` syntax does not work with 1.3.7 with or without the `type:module`. You can see each failure by clicking on the red checks here: https://github.com/pathikrit/node-visionect/pull/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [axios-curlirize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-curlirize) versions [v1.4.0 (deprecated)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-curlirize/v/1.4.0) and [v2.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-curlirize/v/2.0.0) are using ESM.

If you want to use CJS, you would need to use version [v1.3.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-curlirize/v/1.3.7) or lower instead, but looking at the errors you've posted, they are being caused by installing the wrong version of the package.

The version set on `package.json` is using caret (i.e. `^1.3.7`) which would mean your package manager (`npm`, `yarn`, etc.) is trying to install the latest available minor version: `v1.4.0` - which is using ESM and is something you probably don't want to use in this case.

To fix this, you can use tilde (i.e. `~1.3.7`) to avoid updating to future minor releases and lock the version to accept patch releases only (`v1.3.x`):

1. In the `curlirize` branch, update the `package.json` and set `axios-curlirize` to `~1.3.7`.

   ```json
   "axios-curlirize": "~1.3.7"
   ```
2. Run `yarn install` to update `yarn.lock` and the dependencies.
3. Run `yarn test` and `axios-curlirize` related issues should be resolved.

For more info about `package.json` dependency versions, please see: [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22343224/7013346)

Comment: Yup! That was it - I pored over every character that might differ between my code and sources I found on Github and I missed the `~` vs `^` ....

Comment: OTOH, this is a bad usage of SEMVER by axios-curlirize -> Going from CJS to ESM is a major breaking change and they should not have used a minor version increment to do that!

Comment: I agree. Though, looking at their releases from GitHub, they don't have a release for `v1.4.0`. I'm guessing `v1.4.0` was an accident / mistake and they couldn't do anything but deprecated it since they weren't able to unpublish it from npm.