# NodeJs server help for this issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

server>npm start

> server@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

(node:12504) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
D:\TerProject\server\server.js:1
import express from 'express'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, go to the `package.json` file and add `"type": "module"`.
This error mainly occurs when you use the import keyword to import a module in Node.js. Or when you omit the `type="module"` attribute in a `script` tag.

For Reference : ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 0):

Add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file.