# Can't use jest in module files for testing in node js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules

I was trying to use jest for testing my module files and got encountered to error, I looked for online help, tried running test by changing it to a cjs file but wasn't successful.
The error I encountered:

```js
 FAIL  tests/sum.test.cjs
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                               
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
```

more specifically

```js
  Details:

    <edited_path>\event-management-system\tests\sum.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import sum from '../sum.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runtime@29.5.0/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.227 s
Ran all test suites.
```

The files I used to test was
`sum.js`

```js
const sum = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};

export default sum;
```

`sum.test.js`

```js
import sum from '../sum.js';

describe('sum module', () => {
  test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Please help me with this specific error

Edit:

I have tried out
Changing file types to .mjs files
or
Use require syntax instead of import.
and
using .cjs file time for the test file.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "event-management-system",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/*.test.js"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your package.json file.

Comment: @VishnuSatheesh please have a look I have added package.json in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with jest for handling ECMAScript Modules, and the updates are experimental. If you want to use jest for any project where you have described `"type": "module"` then have look to this [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules).

Your problem can be fixed by adding a testing script provided below in the `package.json` file,

```json
"scripts": {
    "test":"node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

In your `package.json` add this

```
{
  "type": "module",   
}
```

or

Change your file types to `.mjs` files

or

Use `require` syntax instead of `import`.

you can see some of these solutions here:
["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: Tried all of these, nothing helped!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for considering, the issue was solved by adding the script for testing in `package.json` file, as:

```json
    "test":"node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
```

It is described [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules), however, it is experimental and may change over time.