# Angular chart.js "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I would like to use chart.js but I have some problem. In my opinion this problem block import correctly this library.

I added also this. Did not helped.

```
"type": "module",
```

I try this but I think it`s another problem
["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-add-edit',
  templateUrl: './line-add-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-add-edit.component.scss']
})

export class LineAddEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chartCanvas') private chartCanvasRef!: ElementRef;
  private chartInstance: Chart | undefined;
```

.html

```
<div>
    <canvas #chartCanvas
      (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
      (mouseout)="onMouseOut()"
      style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;"
    ></canvas>
</div>
```

.error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at scripts.js:7:1)
```

[image]

tsconfig

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "dupa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@material/form-field": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/grid-list": "^4.0.0",
    "@material/theme": "^14.0.0",
    "@material/toolbar": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.37",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.1",
    "material-icons": "^1.13.8",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. downgrade chart.js to version 3.9 resolve the problem

```
npm uninstall chart.js
npm install chart.js@3.9.0
```