# Export a JSON database to use in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, database

I just barely started learning JavaScript by myself and have a question to ask.

I have a JSON database I created, and a JavaScript file connecting to this same db, on another js file I have a function that I call with a button, how can I get the data from my JSON database into the js file with the function?

Here's how my code looks like right now

index.html

```html
<head><script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="db_connection.js" type="module"></script></head><body><button onclick="showData()">Show Data</button></body>
```

script.js

```
import { data } from "./db_connection.js"; function showData() {   console.log(data[0].name); }
```

db_connection.js

```
import data from "./database.json" assert { type: "json" }; export default { data };
```

database.json

```json
[   { "id": 1, "name": "Jason", "year": 2020 },   { "id": 2, "name": "Freddy", "year": 2021 } ]
```

The console returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: showData is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)