# Cannot use import statement outside a module using NPM

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

This is my first time trying this kind of setup.

I'm following this [article](https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/reading-google-sheets-data-using-javascript-with-google-sheets-reader/) to develop a "Google Sheets Reader".

Here is what I have tried:

1. Executed this command `npm install g-sheets-api --save-dev` in my local project folder, which created a `node_modules` folder and some files in it.
2. Cloned this [project](https://github.com/bpk68/g-sheets-api/tree/master) inside my project folder.

[image: List item]

3. When I browse the page, it shows the error in console.
   [image]

**index.html:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="output">...loading</main>        
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
import GSheetProcessor from '../src/gsheetsprocessor.js';  

....  

....
```

In the `index.js`, i have modified the file reference path to `../src/gsheetsprocessor.js`.

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the `index.html` as follows by referencing the JS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="output">...loading</main>

    <script type="module">
      //import { GSheetProcessor } from "../src/gsheetsprocessor.js";
    </script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also updated the `index.js` file by commenting the `import` statement.

```
//import GSheetProcessor from '../src/gsheetsprocessor.js';
....
....
GSheetProcessor(
....
....
)
```

The error in console now is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GSheetProcessor is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Comment: @GreenSaiko I have added `type:module` and executed `npm start`. That resulted in errors. When I replaced `import` command with this `parse = require('../src/gsheetsprocessor.js');` the console error says `require` is not defined.

Comment: Just to clarify your project folders structure, where are `index.html` and `index.js` located, since I can't see them in the provided image? And is `gsheetsprocessor.js` inside the `src` folder?

Comment: the `index.html` & `index.js` are inside the `demo` folder. The `gsheetsprocessor.js ` file is inside the `src` folder.

Comment: Just add `type="module"` to `<script src="index.js"` and it should work. If you comment out the import, there's an obvious reason something wouldn't be defined.

Comment: @sukesh I tried some things but couldn't get it to run. Also, **a lot** of modules used in this project are deprecated and with a fresh install you got like 60 vulnerabilities. I think something's wrong with the dependency configuration, since renovate has created a dependency issue on the GitHub. Sorry, my little to nothing expertise cant resolve this