Importing DeepL API in local file leads to error message (Cannot use import statement outside a module)
Context:
My overall goal is to import a bunch of multiple-choice questions and the corresponding answers from a website into a Google Form. Since I'll need to do this more often I thought I could write a script to make the process more efficient. So I wrote a short JS script for execution in the website's console. It generates and returns a code made for Google Apps Script which then creates a form with all of the questions.
Now I need to automatically translate the form's content (during GAS code generation). I want to use DeepL and since it has no way of translating a website, I decided to use DeepL API in my JS code. Unfortunately, I'm still pretty new to JavaScript - and that's most likely the actual problem... (Now I'm asking myself if my approach has any positive effect on the efficiency I mentioned before... )
The issue:
When executing my JS code, I only get the following error message:

UncaughtSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

The error appears in the first line of my code:
import * as deepl from "deepl-node";

The project directory contains a downloaded copy of the website as an HTML file (so that I can use the API). I execute JS code in that HTML file (I open it in Chrome from localhost). And of course, I have also installed deepl-node (and node.js).
Now I need to know how to fix this. Is it impossible to import the API and use it locally?
From my code:


import * as deepl from "deepl-node";
const DEEPL_API_AUTH_KEY = " <my API key> ";
const translator = new deepl.Translator(DEEPL_API_AUTH_KEY);

const DEFAULT_POINTS = 2;
const qAndA = [];

let questionId = 0;
for (const e of document.querySelectorAll("h3")) {
  qAndA.push([
    "\n\n// QUESTION " + questionId +
    "\nquestion" + questionId + " = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();\nquestion" + questionId + '.setTitle("' +
    (
      await translator.translateText(e.innerHTML, "en", "de", {
        splitSentences: "nonewlines",
        preserveFormatting: true,
      })
    ).text +
    '");\nquestion' + questionId + ".setChoices([",
  ]); // Creates sub-array for each question, content: question title

  // and so on...

  for (let i = 0; i < qAndA.length; i++) {
    qAndA[i] = qAndA[i].join("");
  }
  const gasCode = qAndA.join("");
  console.log(gasCode);
<!-- Basic structure of the website: -->
<ol>
  <li>
    <h3>First question???</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Option A</li>
      <li>Option B</li>
      <li>Option C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h3>Second question???</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Option A</li>
      <li>Option B</li>
      <li>Option C</li>
      <li>Option D</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <!-- and so on... -->

</ol>



(I know it hurts to read this, but I thought I could just do it quick and dirty and never need to open the code again but that didn't turn out that well...)
Thank you so much in advance!

If you're running it in a browser environment and importing your js file via a script tag, you need to: 1. import the deepl-node module via a script tag before your script (before here means simply in some line above) and 2. add the type="module" inside the script tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Do you have a package.json file to manage the dependencies in your project? You might need to add 'type':'module' to your package.json
Also note that deepl-node is intended to be used in the backend, not the frontend as it would leak your API key otherwise: https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-node/issues/3

Thank you, @rajniszp ! I did what you said (at least I think so), and my import now looks like that:
`
`
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I also tried adding 'type':'module' to package.json, as @Gaze advised (thank you too!) but I still get those two error messages.
I checked the dependencies, too (and reached a point where I completely lost track of what I was even doing). I installed everything deepl-node needs, with no effect :/

Oh, and thanks for the advice on the API key, but I won't ever share the code with anyone else. I'm just trying to create a productivity tool for myself, so that shouldn't be an issue.

404 means the resource (script) was not found. I see you have "localhost" in the url, so I guess you are running some kind of a server. You need to ensure it is accessible via some url and provide the correct path in script tag
