Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module , i wanna show alert on my website
When I import the code from search.js into scripts.js, the alert isn't showing up.
search.js code
class Search {
  constructor() {
    alert("hello, I am a search");
    
  }
}

export default Search;

scripts.js code
import "../css/style.css"

// alert("hello");
// Our modules / classes
import MobileMenu from "./modules/MobileMenu"
import HeroSlider from "./modules/HeroSlider"
import GoogleMap from "./modules/GoogleMap"
import Search from "./modules/Search"

// Instantiate a new object using our modules / classes
const mobileMenu = new MobileMenu()
const heroSlider = new HeroSlider()
const googleMap = new GoogleMap()
const search = new Search()
console.log(search);

// Allow new JS and CSS to load in browser without a traditional page refresh
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}


i want show alert on website

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

It appears your trying to use import in a none bundled environment,.  You can set the type="module" on the calling script, but even after that -> import "../css/style.css" is a none standard way of importing CSS into the browser and was likely done during bundling.

If you want to import stuff on a web page, you need to do it in a "module" script, like this:
<script type="module">
  import "../css/style.css"
  // and other imports...
</script>

